# Find the coordinates of the tangent points of the ellipse

Tags: calculus

Equation of the ellipse is $x^2+4y^2 = 1$
There are two tangent lines, each with slope $\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$.
Find the coordinates of the tangent points ($\pm a, \mp b)$

My instructor gave us hints to first use implicit differentiation, of the equation
and I did get $\frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{-x}{4y}$

Another hint was to find $(a, -b)$ such that $\frac{-a}{-4b} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and also $ a^2+4b^2 = 1$

He told us to solve these equations simultaneously.

But I do not how to find the equations simultaneously.
Please allow me to understand the procedure. The answer was already given to me, I just need to practice.

For your information answer: $ a = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} b = \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First equation is $\frac{a}{4b}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ From here $a=2\sqrt{3}b$. Substitute $a$ with  $2\sqrt{3}b$ in the second equatiion $(2\sqrt{3}b)^2+4b^2=1$. Sove for $b$

$12b^2+4b^2=1$ $b^2=\frac{1}{16}$ $b=\pm\frac{1}{4}$ then the correspondig values of $a$ are

$b=\frac{1}{4}, a=2\sqrt{3}.\frac{1}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$,

$b=-\frac{1}{4},  a=2\sqrt{3}.(-\frac{1}{4})=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: I actually figured it out later on, but thanks for the confirmation :)